# Which Intent for Settings - Data usage

Tags: android, android-intent

I spent several hours by searching correct Intent for launching **Data usage Activity** in Android Settings. Unfortunetly i found nothing (on web and also here).

I also tried reflection (in a case of private field) but also without result. I will be glad for any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: start the activity by hand. look in your logcat. the intent is logged. voila

Comment: @njzk2 i don't think so. I already tested it and intent is not logged.

Comment: that's probably a fragment, then ?

Comment: @njzk2 anything is logged so i cannot use your approach.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try...

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
            "com.android.settings",
            "com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

This worked for me. I found it from the link to data usage in the KitKat QuickSettings source code.

Comment: There is no guarantee that this will work across devices and Android versions.

Comment: @CommonsWare and what is? Is there an elegant way to find out if the above works on a specific device?

Comment: @JohnSmith: "and what is?" -- there is no `Intent` action to drive to this screen. "Is there an elegant way to find out if the above works on a specific device?" -- well, that depends upon your definition of "works". You can see if the `Intent` will resolve via `PackageManager` and `resolveActivity()`, or just catching the `ActivityNotFoundException`. However, it's not out of the question that the `Intent` will resolve, but then the manufacturer simply craps out on the Settings side. *Probably* that won't happen.

Comment: Thanks. I have resolved this by catching the exception and then move on to the next best one available, ACTION_SETTINGS.

Comment: @JohnSmith is it pretty much guaranteed that this will at least work on devices >= 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at Android Settings manifest file and find activity section named "Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity", it doesn't seem like it has an intent for being launched. Its intent filter has only one action tag(MAIN).

In Settings/AndroidManifest.xml,

```
<activity android:name="Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity"
...>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="com.android.settings.SHORTCUT" />
    </intent-filter>
...
</activity>
```

As you can see in this code, there is no custom action intent defined here.

Comment: Can you add some snippet of code? Now im little confused from your reply.

Comment: I don't think that's possible since it does not provide any extra action intent. Maybe you can start activity with its class name, but I am not sure if that is allowed. For your information, you might check settings constants here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

Comment: I cannot find data usage summary settings from those constants but at least you can start a settings activity which is close to data usage summary. I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Android Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). They are talking about a `ACTION_MANAGE_NETWORK_USAGE` Intent.

Comment: Sorry but this won't launch data usage intent in Settings but thanks for answer.

Comment: This will launch a prompt for the intent, with various resulting app resolvers, such as Exchange Services, Maps, Gmail, Youtube... None of them are the system preferences the OP asks for. gsysko's answer seems to work, but maybe not consistently across different manufacturers as pointed out by CommonsWare