# android dumpsys batteryinfo vs android dumpsys batterystats

Tags: android, linux, adb

Can anyone tell me how does the `adb shell dumpsys` work internally? I suppose this command reads the `/proc` fs somehow, but this is just my understanding.

It seems that android sdk 19 onwards, following command is not supported-

```
adb shell dumpsys batteryinfo
```

It has been replaced by

```
adb shell dumpsys batterystats
```

I would like to know if any documentation (link) is available, where detailed information about this can be found.

Comment: After answering below, I searched for the change in service name and found this previous SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201659/whats-android-adb-shell-dumpsys-tool-and-its-benefits?rq=1.  The one from Joe has additional detail and I would recommend reviewing it.

Comment: I assume that only "adb shell dumpsys batterystats" is available since Kitkat, right?

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes, in Kitkat it is "adb shell dumpsys batterystats" while in JB and earlier versions it was "adb shell dumpsys batteryinfo"

Comment: @darthvading Thanks. Do you know perhaps how to read from its output, to get the battery consumption of a specific app? I've tried doing so, but my calculation doesn't match the one on the official battery-info screen. If you know the answer to it, please write it down here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312038/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the source code for [dumpsys](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/cmds/dumpsys/dumpsys.cpp), you can see that it simply requests a instance of the service from the default service manager and then calls the service `dump()` method (which is an interface of [IBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder.html)) passing STDOUT and the command line args:

```
sp<IServiceManager> sm = defaultServiceManager();
...
sp<IBinder> service = sm->checkService(services[i]);
...
int err = service->dump(STDOUT_FILENO, args);
```

In your example above, the service in question would appear to have been renamed from `batteryinfo` to `batterystats`