# Android - launching intent for Restrict Background Data

Tags: android, android-intent

Any idea what would be intent to launch application specific Data usage settings to enable/disable Restrict Background Data.

To launch general setting screen following is the post i referred and it worked also
[Which Intent for Settings - Data usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022773/which-intent-for-settings-data-usage)

But I need to launch for specific package id.
Please check this launch screen

This screen is for Gmail
[image: This screen is for Gmail]

Looking for an intent with parameters to launch this screen programmatically.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings",
            "com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity"));
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Solution menitioned by you is already available in the link provided in question.It launches Data Usage screen with 3 tabs, what I am looking for is, to launch the screen with a specific package.